# Filtering pandas csv dataframe with Datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, stock

My csv looks like this: 
|Date|Open|High|Low|Close|Adj Close|Vol|
|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
|1/29/2008|9.5|9.99|8.57|8.75|0.702589|1489000|

I am reading multiple csv files in the list, with first column "Date" as index and parsing the dates as well:

```
all_max = []
for f in max_files:
    data_instance = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(max_path, f), index_col=0, parse_dates=['Date'])
    all_max.append(data_instance)
```

I want to find the records in the range of **startdate** and **enddate**.

```
startdate = pd.to_datetime("2010-7-7").date()
enddate = pd.to_datetime("2010-7-15").date()
locs = all_max[0]['Date'].iloc[startdate:enddate]
print(locs)
```

But I get an **ERROR**

```
KeyError: 'Date'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-580774846bf5> in <module>
      1 startdate = pd.to_datetime("2010-7-7").date()
      2 enddate = pd.to_datetime("2010-7-15").date()
----> 3 locs = all_max[0]['Date'].iloc[startdate:enddate]
      4 print(locs)
```

Comment: Do not post images of traceback text and data. Please read the [help documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and reformat the question. Look at examples of other questions to see how to show dataframe content.

Comment: have a look. I don't know why it's not rendering the table properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your dates are the index, so you're getting a key error when trying to select using the "Date" column that doesn't exist. Here's a toy example of how you can select using an index.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05'],
    'this': [5,2,2,5,5], 
    'that': [3,3,3,3,3]},
    )

df.to_csv('dates.csv', index=False)

dates  = pd.read_csv('dates.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=['Date'])

dates = dates.loc[(dates.index > '2022-01-01') & (dates.index <= '2022-01-03')]
```

Output:

```
            this    that
Date        
2022-01-02  2       3
2022-01-03  2       3
```

Answer (score 1):

[`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is for integer indexing—i.e. by row position.

Try using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) instead.  Also note that pandas accepts dates as strings and does the necessary conversion for you.

```
startdate = "2010-7-7"
enddate = "2010-7-15"
selection = all_max[0].loc[startdate:enddate]
dates = selection.index
```